# C# Struct No Parameterless Constructor? See what I need to accomplish

Tags: c#, dll, constructor, struct, dllimport

I am using a struct to pass to an unmanaged DLL as so -

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct valTable
        {
            public byte type;
            public byte map;
            public byte spare1;
            public byte spare2;
            public int par;
            public int min;
            public byte[] name;
            public valTable()
            {
                name = new byte[24];
            }
        }
```

The code above will not compile because VS 2005 will complain that "Structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors". In order to pass this struct to my DLL, I have to pass an array of struct's like so `valTable[] val = new valTable[281];`

What I would like to do is when I say `new`, the constructor is called and it creates an array of bytes like I am trying to demonstrate because the DLL is looking for that byte array of size 24 in each dimension.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a [fixed size buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx) - which I suspect you really want anyway, so as to get the data "inline" in the struct (rather than a reference to an array elsewhere).

```
public fixed byte name[24];
```

You'll need to declare the struct as unsafe as well though.

Note that any "solution" which requires calling a static method or providing any kind of custom constructor will fail with your explicit goal of being able to create an array of these structs.

Comment: I had no idea that the `fixed` keyword could be used like this, and I have wanted something like this several times. I....I....I love you, man!

Comment: @Jeffrey: Can't say I've ever used it myself, but I had to write about it for C# in Depth :)

Comment: @Mitch: Thanks, I've added the link into the answer.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I have C# in Depth, and I read it and loved it. Somehow I missed that part. I once put nine integer variables in a struct and mocked-up array access using a switch statement, just to have a stack-allocated array!

Comment: @Jeffrey: be careful with it. It's easy to get it wrong. See http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/27/what-s-the-difference-between-fixed-and-fixed.aspx for some thoughts on that. Frankly, much of the time I'd probably go with your nine-integer solution. :-)

Comment: @Eric Lippert - Thanks for the link! I will be careful. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend to write this code.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct valTable
{
    public byte type;
    public byte map;
    public byte spare1;
    public byte spare2;
    public int par;
    public int min;
    public byte[] name;

    static public valTable Create()
    {
        valTable vT = new valTable();
        vT.name = new byte[24];
        return vT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Struct constructors are similar to class constructors, except for the following differences:

- Structs cannot contain explicit
  parameterless constructors. Struct
  members are automatically initialized
  to their default values.
- A struct cannot have an initializer
  in the form: base (argument-list).

This means that

```
A default(parameterless) constructor for a struct could set different
values than the all-zeroed state which would be unexpected behavior. The
.Net Runtime therefore prohabits default constructors for struct.
```

The typical way to get around this scenario is to create a static method
that will create your new instance, initialize it the way you want, and
return it. This is the way it is done in .NET to get structures initialized
with specific values.

---

ref; 
[**Structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors. WHY?**](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/13/69987.aspx)

Comment: The .net framework makes a couple of fundamental assumptions about value types: (1) When an array of any type is created, there's no need to do anything but zero out the memory; (2) when copying a field or variable of any type, there's no need to do anything but copy the bytes.  A related notion is that performing a shallow clone of an object should likewise do nothing but clone the bytes of any value types fields therein.

Answer (score 4):

Building on [Asad Butt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372061/c-struct-no-parameterless-constructor-see-what-i-need-to-accomplish/2372134#2372134), you can create a static method to perform the work of your constructor like so:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct valTable
{
    public byte type;
    public byte map;
    public byte spare1;
    public byte spare2;
    public int par;
    public int min;
    public byte[] name;
    public valTable()

    public static valTable NewTable()
    {
        valTable tbl = new valTable();
        tbl.name = new byte[24];
        return tbl;
    }
}
```

You'll see classes in the .NET Framework following this pattern already. [`Guid.NewGuid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) immediately springs to mind. There may be others.

Comment: this would have been my first choice but Jon Skeet's seems simpler

Comment: Why do you have `public valTable()` in there?

Answer (score 2):

Not the cleanest fix, but you could just add a parameter and never use it?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct valTable
    {
        public byte type;
        public byte map;
        public byte spare1;
        public byte spare2;
        public int par;
        public int min;
        public byte[] name;
        public valTable(int x)
        {
            name = new byte[24];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I voted -1 on this one since it promotes code that is misleading and not very logical. There are cleaner ways to do this (such as using a static create method).

Comment: Counteracted the -1 vote.  Dummy parameters are a little annoying, but hardly unknown.  The normal IDisposable pattern has a dummy parameter, for example (if a class doesn't have a finalizer, its Dispose method should never be called with a value of 'false').

Comment: Agree with counteracted. work arounds produce other problems, for example buffer.blockcopy and byte[].copyto will both fail on fixed fields.  The language restriction makes sense to avoid common errors, but the 'proper' way should not require writing a boat load of work around code.

Answer (score -2):

For what you need to do you really need a class I think. A struct already implements a parameterless constructor by default which is why you cant define another one.

Comment: He's passing this struct to a dll.

Comment: This is a bad answer.. it should be deleted.